# Add azure vm to Active Directory during deployment using powershell and azure runbooks

Tags: powershell, azure, active-directory

Is there a way to add an Azure VM to an Active Directory Domain during deployment using Azure runbooks and powershell?

I have a Runbook in Azure which uses PowerShell. PowerShell calls a template to deploy a VM as below. I would prefer to do this using PowerShell rather than ARM template, is there a way to do this?

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroup `
    -TemplateUri $vm_template_uri -TemplateParameterObject $ServerParameters
```

Comment: a lot better to do that with arm template, but if you want to do it with powershell - do it. `Enter-pssesession` will let you connect to the vm and run commands

Comment: Have a look at this link https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/igorpag/2016/01/25/azure-arm-vm-domain-join-to-active-directory-domain-with-joindomain-extension/ it shows how to do it using an extension with PowerShell.

Comment: can you recommend a template for this, i tried using one here but it didnt work  : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/201-vm-domain-join-existing/azuredeploy.json

Comment: I tried the template but keep getting the following error - Template deployment returned the following errors:

09:06:11 -         "code": "VMExtensionProvisioningError",
09:06:11 -         "message": "VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'joindomain'. Error message: \"Exception(s) occured while joining Domain 'domain.local'\"."

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine with me:
[How to join a VM to a domain by PowerShell in Azure](https://mikewu.org/azure/how-to-join-a-vm-to-a-domain-by-powershell-in-azure)

```
$DomainName = "your_domain_name"
$VMName = "your_VM_Name"
$credential = Get-Credential your_Domain_account
$ResourceGroupName = "your_RG_name" 
Set-AzVMADDomainExtension -DomainName $DomainName -VMName $VMName -Credential $credential -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -JoinOption 0x00000001 -Restart -Verbose
```